Texturing a mesh using other mesh part


Idk how to explain that because if i knew i would find a solution already, but ill try my best lmao:
lets say i have 2 mesh parts, how do i make the second mesh part change the texture of the first mesh part when theyre touching each other?
also note that i dont want to make any uv cuts, so boolean wont be a good choice
image example below or above idk:

Combine these meshes and texture the whole perhaps?

Create 3 cubes, 2 of them are overlapping and have a different material, the third one is the boolean object (here it is displayed as Bounds). Give a Boolean modifier to cube 1 and 2 with cube 3 as boolean Object, one modifier is in Difference mode, the other one is in Intersect mode:

